# Select from multiple tables oracle

Tags: oracle, select

I'm new in Oracle. I have a table that lists tablenames of database. Its name is "`AD_Table`". I want to select `ID table`, and `createdby` from `ad_table` list. For example in ad_table it has one column name tablename that represents table name in database:

```
tablename
---------
AD_Tab1
AD_Tab2
AD_Tab3
AD_Tab4
AD_Tab5
AD_Tab6
AD_Tab7
AD_Tab8
AD_Tab9
AD_Tab10
```

I want query like this :

```
SELECT 
createdby
from (SELECT TABLENAME FROM AD_TABLE)
```

but it won't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you please post the pictures of tables?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can have many tables with the same name, on different schemas;
assuming that you need to find all the tables, and their owners, whose names are contained in your table, you can try with something like this:

```
select owner, table_name
from AD_table AD
inner join dba_tables DBA ON ( dba.table_name = UPPER(ad.tableName))
```

Notice that you need to log in with a user having rights to make a select on `DBA_TABLES` to run this query.

Comment: I think he wants the information like SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER') who created this tables.